# value of particular field not updating in for loop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two for loops,the value inside inner for loop is not updating with the value of outer for loop.
I have 2 arrays,

```
     let getExhibitors= [{"_id":"5c78102829c1cc00082c9956","title":"Accenture","sponsorSortOrder":1,"sortOrder":1,"__v":1,"beconDetails":[],"productDemos":[],"sponsorTags":[],"exhibitorTags":[],"eventId": "5c78088a29c1cc00082c990b","entityId": "5c78102829c1cc00082c9956","favourite":true,"notes":'hey it is exhibitor'}]
     let exhibitorsArray= [{"_id":"5d7797029f3ae4000821d2df","favourite":true,"entityId":"5c78109529c1cc00082c9959","module Id":"EXHIBITORS_MODULE","eventId":"5c78088a29c1cc00082c990b","__v":0,"modifiedDate":"2019-09-10T12:34:48.993Z","creationDate":"2019-09-10T12:28:50.526Z","comments":"","notes":"",},{"_id":"5d5cf3d8adaac20007cbcc12","favourite":false,"entityId":"5c78102829c1cc00082c9956","moduleId":"EXHIBITORS_MODULE","eventId":"5c78088a29c1cc00082c990b","__v":0,"modifiedDate":"2019-09-17T10:04:03.891Z","creationDate":"2019-08-21T07:33:44.077Z","comments":"","notes":"hey it is exhibitor","id":"5d5cf3d8adaac20007cbcc12"}]


            for(let i=0;i<exhibitorsArray.length;i++){
          console.log("inside first forloop ",exhibitorsArray[i]);

             for(let j=0;j<getExhibitors.length;j++){
              console.log("inside second forloop",getExhibitors[j]);
              if((exhibitorsArray[i].entityId==getExhibitors[j].entityId ) && (exhibitorsArray[i].eventId==getExhibitors[j].eventId)){
                console.log("exhibitor present",getExhibitors[j],exhibitorsArray[i]);
                  getExhibitors[j].favourite=exhibitorsArray[i].favourite                    
                  getExhibitors[j].notes=exhibitorsArray[i].notes

                console.log("exhibitors final",getExhibitors);

             }
         }
        }
```

here value of exhibitorsArray[i].favourite is not assigning to  getExhibitors[j].favourite and value of exhibitorsArray[i].notes  is not assigning to getExhibitors[j].notes,I mean ,value inside the console "exhibitors final" is retaining the same,not updating.

Please help me out to solve it.

Comment: Hi @yoga .

Did you have a moment to read my answer? 
If you found it useful please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer for your question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is why assignment operation failed.

Both `getExhibitors[j].entityId` and `getExhibitors[j].eventId` do not exist at all. You should also check if this,`loadedSynchData[i].eventId` really exists since the data for this array `loadedSynchData` is not provided yet.

Comment: As tested, your assignment operation works fine but let us terminate these 2 lines with semi colon: ``getExhibitors[j].favourite=exhibitorsArray[i].favourite;``                    
                                   ``getExhibitors[j].notes=exhibitorsArray[i].notes;``

Comment: Bro, why did you add ``favourite`` and ``notes`` to the array namely, ``getExhibitors`` ?  Are we not assuming that this array is lacking those key-value pairs and we want to get them from the second array namely, ``exhibitorsArray`` ? If yes, let us remove ``favourite`` and ``notes`` from ``getExhibitors`` first and then run the code again.

Comment: No,the scenario is like that..getExhibitors array also contains favourite and notes field,I just want to update the values in getExhibitors by values in exhibitorsArray, to update the ui components@CCC

Comment: Bro, the update you want is working but why you couldn't see is that the values  of ``getExhibitors[j].notes``  and ``exhibitorsArray[i].notes``  are not different before you even run your code. So change one of them first and then check if ``getExhibitors[j].notes`` gets updated with the value of ``exhibitorsArray[i].notes``.

Comment: Apart from that, you can see that the value of  ``getExhibitors[j].favourite`` is ``true`` before running the code and after running it,  ``getExhibitors[j].favourite`` gets updated with the value of ``exhibitorsArray[i].favourite`` which is ``false``

Answer (score 0):

One of the keys you are using is wrong (entityId is _id).

You didn't provide loadedSynchData so I cannot properly test my code.

Please try the following:

```
for (let i = 0; i < exhibitorsArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < getExhibitors.length; j++) {
       if ((exhibitorsArray[i].entityId == getExhibitors[j]._id) && (loadedSynchData[i].eventId == getExhibitors[j].eventId)) {
           console.log("exhibitor present", getExhibitors[j], exhibitorsArray[i]);
           getExhibitors[j].favourite = exhibitorsArray[i].favourite
           getExhibitors[j].notes = exhibitorsArray[i].notes
       }
   }
}
```